# how can I compile Ortep3 on Ubuntu?

Tags: compiling, gcc

I recently compiled [ortep3](https://ornl-ndav.github.io/ortep/source.html) on an older CentOS server using `gfortran -o ortep3 ortep.f -lpgplot -lX11`. I think the `gfortran` version was 6.5 or something like that. My version of `gfortran` is: `gcc version 9.2.1`

I would like now to compile ORTEP3 on some Ubuntu machines version 18.04 or later. when I try to compile `ortep`, I get errors, such as:

```
Error: Actual argument contains too few elements for dummy argument ‘itxt’ (1/72) at (1)
```

and warnings such as:

```
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 10 at (1)
```

I have tried using legacy code flag `-ff2c`, which has no effect. `libx11`, and `pgplot` are both installed and operational.

I have tried compiling with `fort77`, which compiles, but the compiled code will not run.
Trying to compile with `gfortran`, `ortep.f` will not compile.

LD_TRACE From the CentOS server:

```
$ LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 ./Working_ortep3 
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc82f42000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f185a9cf000)
libgfortran.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3 (0x00007f185a89d000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f185a74e000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f185a734000)
libquadmath.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007f185a6ea000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f185a4f9000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f185a4ce000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f185a4c8000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f185ab51000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f185a4c2000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f185a4ba000)
libbsd.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f185a4a0000)
```

In an effort to match the place where I was able to build and run ortep3, I have gone through and installed packages that match the libraries of those dependent on the working version of `ortep3`. I did end up installing:

```
sudo apt-get install libxdmcp-dev libbsd-dev
```

Errors still persist.

I'm no longer working on the server that I was able to compile ortep3 on. I can ask about it, but I finished the job (install a functional version of ortep3) when I was able to compile it there.

**Here is a list of just the errors:**

```
$ gfortran -w -g -o ortep3 ortep.f -lpgplot -lX11 
ortep.f:576:36:

  576 |       CALL SIMBOL(W(2,1),W(3,1),HGT,' ',0.,-1)
      |                                    1
Error: Actual argument contains too few elements for dummy argument ‘itxt’ (1/72) at (1)
ortep.f:577:36:

  577 |       CALL SIMBOL(W(2,2),W(3,2),HGT,' ',0.,-2)
      |                                    1
Error: Actual argument contains too few elements for dummy argument ‘itxt’ (1/72) at (1)
ortep.f:3678:27:

 3678 |       CALL SIMBOL(W,W2,HGT,ITEX,THT,NC)
      |                           1
Error: Actual argument contains too few elements for dummy argument ‘itxt’ (8/72) at (1)
ortep.f:3934:48:

 3934 |   185 if (nout.ge.0) WRITE (NOUT,176)I,maksym(1,fsym)
      |                                                1
Error: Actual argument contains too few elements for dummy argument ‘gp’ (12/2304) at (1)
ortep.f:1258:19:

 1258 |       CALL AXEQB(A,V,V,1)
      |                   1
Error: Actual argument contains too few elements for dummy argument ‘x’ (3/9) at (1)
ortep.f:2084:16:

 2084 |   945 CALL PROJ(D(1,65),DP(1,65),X,XO,VIEW,1,65,L)
      |                1
Error: Actual argument contains too few elements for dummy argument ‘d’ (198/387) at (1)
ortep.f:2117:16:

 2117 |       CALL PROJ(V1,DP,X,XO,VIEW,1,1,1)
      |                1
Error: Actual argument contains too few elements for dummy argument ‘d’ (4/387) at (1)
ortep.f:2123:16:

 2123 |   988 CALL PROJ(DA,DP,X,XO,VIEW,1,3,1)
      |                1
Error: Actual argument contains too few elements for dummy argument ‘d’ (9/387) at (1)
ortep.f:2550:32:

 2550 |       CALL SIMBOL(Y(1),Y(2),HGT,' ',TH,7-NJ3)
      |                                1
Error: Actual argument contains too few elements for dummy argument ‘itxt’ (1/72) at (1)
```

I have no idea how this actually started working on the CentOS machine. The `ortep3` code is Fortran77 as far as I know, but the term SIMBOL looks like a typo, I thought it might be SYMBOl, but I didn't need to modify the code to get it to compile previously.

End goals: Add an svg file output function, write a deb package, maintain it.

Comment: A similar error: https://trac.macports.org/ticket/57434
This problem is due to some new, stricter array size checking in gfortran 8.1:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can see [from Repology](https://repology.org/project/ortep3/versions) - the 1.0.3 version is the latest available.
Gentoo has [ebuild](https://gitweb.gentoo.org/repo/gentoo.git/tree/sci-chemistry/ortep3/ortep3-1.0.3-r1.ebuild) for this application at version 1.0.3-r1.

To get it compiled on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS we need to install necessary build tools:

```
sudo apt-get install pgplot5 libx11-dev gfortran
```

and then download `ortep.f` from some Gentoo distfiles mirror:

```
wget http://ftp.corbina.net/pub/Linux/gentoo/distfiles/81/ortep.f
```

(^ this version have `pgplot` disabled, so if you have normally working one from 2000s - use `ortep.f` from https://github.com/ornl-ndav/ortep)

and compile it

```
gfortran -O2 -o ortep3 ortep.f -lpgplot -lX11
```

It will work:

> ```
> $ ./ortep3
> ORTEP-III Version 1.0.3 Jan. 25, 2000
> Enter instruction set file name or "exit" [TEP.IN]:  
> ...
> ```

---

Other possible alternative is to use pre-compiled binaries from https://ornl-ndav.github.io/ortep/compiled.html .